# How to add a button to jQuery.ajax() to use http delete method

Tags: html, http, jquery

I am trying to send an http DELETE method to a URI. After realizing that I cannot do this with plain old html forms, I was told to use jQuery.ajax. I found a few posts on it and this is the code I found that will supposedly do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({ 
        url: '/groups/dissolve/$org_ID', 
        type: 'DELETE', 
            success: function(result) { 
                    // Do something with the result 
            } 
    });
</script>
```

Please bear with me as I have not used jQuery before. What I am trying to do is replace my html form with this code above but I don't know where to start. How do I place a button in there as I would in a regular form? Thanks and please forgive my ignorance!

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$("form").on("submit", function() {
    $.ajax({ 
        url: '/groups/dissolve/$org_ID', 
        type: 'DELETE', 
        success: function(result) { 
                // Do something with the result 
        } 
    });  
});
```

This will bind the AJAX method to the submit action of your form.

Another option is to use method override. This allows you to specify the method (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) in a query string parameter or a hidden field in your form. You will need to check with your specific language and web framework, but most support this in some variation.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.on(...` rather than `.bind(...`?

Comment: Absolutly. .on() is the new API method that replaces .bind() in most cases as of 1.7